# How to make my post api to be able to send data as parameter in python

Tags: python, api, flask, postman

I have this code:

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template
)

import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import re

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")


@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Welcome'


@app.route('/write_text_to_file', methods=['POST'])
def write_text_to_file():
    f = open("str.txt", "w+")
    f.write("hello world")
    f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

EDIT:
MY API includes one functionality which is writing a string to local file system by creating this file. 
What I want to achieve is to be able to pass a string as part of the api request which could be any string and to write the accepted string into a file, now I'm using hard-coded string which get the job done but I want to achieve the ability to send strings dynamically when using this api to write to file.

Comment: You can extract data from the URL as well as the request body by accessing the `request` object. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#the-request-object for details.

Comment: @Nihal what do you mean?

Comment: can you explain your problem step by step? do you want to send data in post request to another route or what?? and where do you want to send the data?

Comment: @Nihal - of course first I'll edit my question.

Comment: from which route do you want to send data and where? please mention all that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

In postman i posted the string in body as raw. then you can get data using 
`request.data` which will be of byte type so you have to use `request.data.decode("utf-8")`

```
@app.route('/write_text_to_file', methods=['POST'])
def write_text_to_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(type(request.data))
        data = request.data.decode("utf-8")
        f = open("str.txt", "w+")
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
    return ''
```

Comment: is this what you want ? @tupac shakur

Comment: And if I want to use 'post' I mean building my api as 'post' and not 'get'?

Comment: how are you using this route? and what are you sending with post request?

Comment: I'm using it as follows: localhost:5000/write_text_to_file (now I did it using postman) and I would like to be able to send data in the body of the request api.

Comment: check my answer now

Comment: When I used postman and changing my code to your suggestion i was getting internal server error 
this is my request : localhost:5000/write_to_text_file and I added in raw section a simple string 'hello' when I sent it I was getting error code 500.

Comment: because you have to return something. but more important thing is are you able to get data into your file

Comment: OK now if I want to be able to test it and to pass a string value from the end user how can I do it?

Comment: see i have updated my answer

Comment: from HTML do you want to send?

Comment: making a unittest in python which asks for an input from the user and send it as the body of the post request

Comment: may be you should ask different question about that, i don't know the correct way